# Confiant "en", ou confiant "dans" + complément ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, syntaxe

Dans un rapport que je suis en train d'écrire, je suis confronté à un dilemme.

Je voudrais écrire :

> J'étais donc confiant *en* la qualité du code que j'écrivais.

Ici la proposition *en* me semble inappropriée, et formulée ainsi :

> J'étais donc confiant *dans* la qualité du code que j'écrivais.

La phrase me semble plus correcte, mais le *dans* me laisse instaisfait.

Quelle est la formulation adéquate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En dehors de quelques expressions figées, la construction

***en*** + article défini (*confiant **en le** xyzt*, *confiant **en la** tuv*) n'est pas régulière.

Brunot la tient même pour "*un affreux barbarisme contraire à la fois à l'usage et à la tradition*",
Pour Grevisse (§933b) il s'agit d' *une excentricité littéraire*...

Te reste alors *confiant **dans** la qualité du code*

Note qu'on pourrait aussi dire (mais peut-être de façon un poil trop soutenue relativement à la nature de ton document)

- *Confiant à l'égard de la qualité du code...*

Et, plus rarement mais cela fonctionnerait aussi :

- *Confiant avec la qualité du code...*

Comment: J'emploie personnellement souvent aussi "Confiant de...", au point que j'avais d'abord commencé ma réponse comme cela... il semble que cela soit totalement erroné car je ne trouve aucune référence. A moins qu'il s'agisse d'un belgicisme...

Comment: Je trouve ton *confiant de* cité dans le Dictionnaire de la langue française Hachette 1875 comme attesté au XVIe et donc un peu vieilli : "*Confiant **de** votre dicte clémence et doulceur, me suis avancé de vous faire...*"

Answer (score 0):

Dans votre exemple, les 2 phrases sont interchangeables interchangeable car on peut être confiant *dans* ou *en* une chose.

Par contre, s'il s'agissait d'une personne, on emploierait de préférence "en".

[source](https://www.francoisenore.com/articles/confiance-dans-ou-en)

Comment: Soit ! Me voilà rasséréné :p Merci pour le lien, ce site a l'air intéressant !

Comment: Je vous conseillerais d'attendre un peu avant de valider ma réponse. Il y a ici des personnes bien plus pointues que moi avec de bien meilleurs références qui pourront sans doute faire une réponse plus complète, voire plus correcte :-)

Comment: Attention! Oui! Laurent S. on peut très bien être *confiant en **une*** mais jamais *confiant en **la***

Comment: @aCOSwt > Si j'en crois ma source, ca n'est pas vraiment interdit, mais effectivement la construction avec "dans" est privilégiée

Comment: @Laurent S. Rien n'interdit effectivement les barbarismes. C'est juste que... cépabo! Rien n'interdit non plus (et heureusement) d'écrire de façon... excentrique... (cf. ma contrib)... c'est juste que je n'ai pas perçu que l'OP pouvait réellement se le permettre dans son document... ;)